# How do I make windows event listener trigger once per keypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a react component and I am trying to have a windows event listener that triggers on each keydown and will react if it is the tab key, but currently it is hitting multiple times each time

Is there anyway to make it so each keydown is trigger once only? Here is the code

```
render() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown',(event) => {
         // here the eventListener should only trigger once per keypress, but it's hitting 4 times
         console.log("event",event);
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show your mystery code that causes this issue?

Comment: @epascarello I have put the mystery code, basically it's at render() and the idea is to trigger it once per keydown but it's hitting multiple times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740073/how-to-detect-keydown-anywhere-on-page-in-a-react-app

Comment: Use keyup instead, or look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466869/force-keydown-event-to-fire-only-once-per-keycode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addEventListener` does not belong into the `render()` function.
There it will create a new event listener on every rerender of that component.

Instead, put it into `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

```
class Component extends React.Component{

  handleKeyDown =(event) =>{
    // here the eventListener should only trigger once per keypress, but it's hitting 4 times
    console.log("event",event);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
   window.addEventListener('keydown',this.handleKeyDown)
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('keydown',this.handleKeyDown)
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={()=>this.setState((state)=>({test:state?.test+1}))}>test</button>
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, setting an event listener on `window` will create a global event listener. You should remove it, when you don't need it anymore, e.g. on `componentWillUnmount`